# how to view memory used by operating system and web server in hyper v

Tags: operating-system, hyper-v

I have a situation where i need to view memory and disk space used by operating systems (windows2012r2 and centos) and web servers (IIS(windows2012r2) and apache(centos)), both of them made as a virtual servers in hyper v.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.

Comment: oh i see! thanks, i'll try "Server Fault" then.